# How to install `pg_recvlogical` to Centos 6?

Tags: centos, software-installation, rpm, postgresql

I have a Centos 6 installed. I did `yum update`.

I need `pg_recvlogical`. I didn't find it using `yum search pg_recvlogical` so I found it mentioned [here](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-sclo-rh/rh-postgresql95-postgresql-contrib-9.5.9-4.el6.x86_64.rpm.html).

So I download it and wanted to install using `rpm -i`, but I quickly got to a tree of unsatisfied dependencies which collide with the installed versions.

How should I do to install just `pg_recvlogical`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

instead of `rpm -i` use yum, it can handle dependencies better.

```
yum install .../.../x.rpm
```

If it doesn't solve the problem your rpm may be not that much for your CentOS version or you have to add some repositories which contains the missing dependencies. In any case it's a better idea to use a repository instead of just downloading an RPM.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a repo for our version of Centos, but could not.

In the end, I simply downloaded [the binaries from PostgreSQL web](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/), and took the `pg_recvlogical` from there. It runs properly with the libraries installed in the system.

Answer (score 0):

first install postgres:

```
sudo yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/postgresql11-libs-11.7-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/postgresql11-11.7-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/postgresql11-contrib-11.7-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
```

then correct your PATH in .bash_profile:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:/usr/pgsql-11/bin/
```